# Js SDK Facebook share image Uncaught Error: invalid version specified

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, laravel-5

I'm trying to share an image from my view to facebook through JS SDK , I'm working with laravel 5.2 and i used this script to get the js sdk file right after the < body >

```
> < script > 
>  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
>       appId      : 'my-app-id',
>       xfbml      : true,
>       version    : 'v2.5'
>     });   };
> 
>   (function(d, s, id){
>      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
>      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
>      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
>      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-
> jssdk')); 
 < /script >
```

and this is the a href

```
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/" data-image="Request::url()" data-title="{{$img->title}}" data-desc="{{ $img->description }}" class="fb_share">
    <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/{{ $img->file_path }}" alt="" width="50" height="50">
</a>
```

this is the script

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 1027291920648034,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });
};

(function(d, debug){var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];if   (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);}(document, /*debug*/ false));

function postToFeed(title, desc, url, image) {
    var obj = {method: 'feed',link: url, picture: image,name: title,description: desc};
    function callback(response) {}
    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}

var fbShareBtn = document.querySelector('.fb_share');
fbShareBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('data-title'),
        desc = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('data-desc'),
        url = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('href'),
        image = fbShareBtn.getAttribute('data-image');
    postToFeed(title, desc, url, image);

    return false;
});


</script>
```

Comment: can we get a test link?

Comment: im working in local !! still Uncaught Error: invalid version specified

Comment: maybe this helps to fix your issue: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: it is hard to say without looking at the rendered html in a browser.

Comment: rhank you :) it works now :)

Comment: you should either answer the question by yourself and explain what the problem was, or delete the whole question.

Comment: Okay ! i just followed your link , get the init function window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 //SDK loaded, initialize it
 FB.init({
  appId      : 'your-app-id',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.2'
 }); } and add the rest of my postfeed function as written in my code ! i solved the invalid version problem !! but now i got the 
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application. !!

Comment: please tell me if you have any idea about this error?

Comment: please google for that error, it is a well known one.

Comment: I did and yet i resolved that problem !! I checkeck my App ID and i get confused with an old Facebook application i creatd before ! so I do approciate your answers trying to help me :) thank you